# how to retrieve LogCat data after use Log.d(); statement as we get logcat information earlier

Tags: logcat, android-logcat

I have just used **Log.d();** statement to debug my app and for this I created a filter configuration.  I got it working so that it shows the feedback.

But Now I deleted this **Log.d();** from my app. But I can't access the Logcat Information as I got earlier.  It's not an error. I just want to get my Logcat as I used before **Log.d();** statement.

Would anyone tell me how !!!!

Comment: Logcat usually have a certain size buffer, after which it rewrite itself. And of course, your logcat logs will automatically gets reset when your device is rebooted.

Comment: Having said that in the previous comment, now as you have already deleted the Log.d(); from your application, you shouldn't get that message in the logcat as well.